# UICollectionView - dynamic cell height?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to display a bunch of collectionViewCells that have different heights. the views are too complex and I don't want to manually calculate the expected height. I want to enforce auto-layout to calculate cell height

Calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` outside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath` breaks collectionView and causes it to crash

Another problem is the cell is not in a separate xib, so I can't manually instantiate a temporary one and use it for height calculation.

Any solutions for this?

```
public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    configureCell(cell, item: items[indexPath.row])
    
    cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Crash happens as soon as `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` is called. If I don't call that method and instead return a size everything works great and cells show up without the calculated size

negative or zero sizes are not supported in the flow layout

```
2015-01-26 18:24:34.231 [13383:9752256] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095aef35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109243bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109499f33 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000107419d9c -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos] + 842
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010741aca9 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 526
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010741651f -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 257
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010742da10 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001074301c6 -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 44
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001073fddb1 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 248
    9                                       0x00000001042b824c _TFC1228BasePaginatingViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView6layoutCSo22UICollectionViewLayout22sizeForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_VSC6CGSize + 700
    10                                     0x00000001042b83d4 _TToFC1228BasePaginatingViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView6layoutCSo22UICollectionViewLayout22sizeForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_VSC6CGSize + 100
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107419e2e -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos] + 988
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010741aca9 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 526
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010741651f -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 257
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010742da10 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 67
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010742e0e9 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 54
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001073f67b8 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 170
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106e3c973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106b0fde8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106b04a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106b0487e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106a7263e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106a7374a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106a73db5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094e3dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094e3d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094d9b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094d9486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010be869f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000106dc3420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    30                                      0x000000010435c709 main + 169
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a0f2145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: It's now very easy to do this ***if you are using a flow layout***.   Perfect tutorial: https://engineering.shopspring.com/dynamic-cell-sizing-in-uicollectionview-fd95f614ef80

Comment: For 2019, including iOS 13, here's the last-word discussion on the issue!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231881/294884

Comment: Another good simple tutorial  https://medium.com/@andrea.toso/uicollectionviewcell-dynamic-height-swift-b099b28ddd23

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) that shows you how to use AutoLayout to dynamically size `UITableViewCell`s. I would think it would be the same for `UICollectionViewCell`.

Basically, though, you end up dequeueing and configuring a prototype cell and grabbing its height. After reading this article, I decided to **NOT** implement this method and just write some clear, explicit sizing code.

Here's what I consider the "secret sauce" for the entire article:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (CGFloat)heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static RWBasicCell *sizingCell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RWBasicCellIdentifier];
    });

    [self configureBasicCell:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:sizingCell];
}

- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell {
    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}
```

---

***EDIT:*** I did some research into your crash and decided that there is no way to get this done without a custom XIB. While that is a bit frustrating, you should be able to cut and paste from your Storyboard to a custom, empty XIB.

Once you've done that, code like the following will get you going:

```
//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> {

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CollectionViewCell *cell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView   *collectionView;
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear...");
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10.0f;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10.0f;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self sizingForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
- (CGSize)sizingForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *title                  = @"This is a long title that will cause some wrapping to occur. This is a long title that will cause some wrapping to occur.";
    static NSString *subtitle               = @"This is a long subtitle that will cause some wrapping to occur. This is a long subtitle that will cause some wrapping to occur.";
    static NSString *buttonTitle            = @"This is a really long button title that will cause some wrapping to occur.";
    static CollectionViewCell *sizingCell   = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sizingCell                          = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
    });
    [sizingCell configureWithTitle:title subtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: Number %d.", subtitle, (int)indexPath.row] buttonTitle:buttonTitle];
    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize cellSize = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    NSLog(@"cellSize: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(cellSize));
    return cellSize;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *title                  = @"This is a long title that will cause some wrapping to occur. This is a long title that will cause some wrapping to occur.";
    static NSString *subtitle               = @"This is a long subtitle that will cause some wrapping to occur. This is a long subtitle that will cause some wrapping to occur.";
    static NSString *buttonTitle            = @"This is a really long button title that will cause some wrapping to occur.";
    CollectionViewCell *cell                = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureWithTitle:title subtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: Number %d.", subtitle, (int)indexPath.row] buttonTitle:buttonTitle];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

The code above (along with a very basic `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and associated XIB) gives me this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. on collectionView it crashes.

Comment: ... crashes where, with what sort of crash?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that sucks that this is not possible to do

Comment: Well, it's not possible the way you want to do it (which, I agree, is a reasonable expectation), but it's still **possible** to use AutoLayout to dynamically size the cells. So, half a win, at least.

Comment: This is a great answer. Would you be willing to post this demo project on GitHub?

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
} here you are using tableview delegate method and on the top you have set it to collectionview delegate and datasource...?

Comment: In the top portion, I am referencing an article discussing `Autolayout` in `UITableViewCell`s. It is in the second portion where I have code specific to `UICollectionViewCell`s.

Comment: We can maintain dynamic height for collection view cell without xib(only using storyboard).

Please check my answer below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161839/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height/41629764#41629764

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked with loading the cell from the bundle instead of dequeuing it from the collection view. However, you might want to remove the first answer regarding UITableView as this question is specifically about UICollectionView, and the first answer results in a crash.

Comment: I need to take in account for the insets. For that I need to subtract 20 (10 left and 10 right) from the fake cell in `sizingForRowAtIndexPath` before filling it with text. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you create a sizing cell once instead of creating it every time in sizingForRowAtIndexPath? To be clear, create once and render each time with different content to get the dynamic heights?

Comment: @Fattie First of all, this is a 5-year-old answer. Second, can you explain how my answer, which references `UICollectionView` all over the place, is **utterly unrelated** to collection views? I'd like to make this better, if possible, but it seems like others have thought it **WAS** helpful already. Can you explain?

Comment: hi @mbm29414 !  sorry - "I would think it would be the same for UICollectionViewCell"   It's simply not, at all. (Try it).  They are hugely fundamentally different.   What you say in the sentences "Basically.." and "I did.." is not correct. (And was not 5 yrs ago!)  Finally note that your image example has fixed, not dynamic, height cells! There are very few good articles around on dynamic collection view cells, this one gives the basics - https://medium.com/@andrea.toso/uicollectionviewcell-dynamic-height-swift-b099b28ddd23   Not to say your answer wasn't helpful, viva the votes!

Comment: @Fattie you are mistaken on your facts. What I said *did* work 5 years ago. The cells are not, actually, fixed height, but dynamic. Anyway, hope you got a shot of dopamine for incorrectly criticizing a stranger on the internet. That way, at least something positive will have resulted from this exchange.

Comment: Hmm, purely technical professional discussions can appear abrupt. There's no personal interaction on here.  Cheers

Answer (score 27):

I just ran into this problem on a UICollectionView and the way that i solved it similar to the answer above but in a pure UICollectionView way.

1. Create a custom UICollectionViewCell that contains whatever you will be filling it with to make it dynamic.  I created its own .xib for it as it seems like the easiest approach.
2. Add constraints in that .xib that allow for the cell to be calculated from top to bottom.  The re-sizing won't work if you haven't accounted for all of the height.  Say you have a view on top, then a label underneath it, and another label underneath that.  You would need to connect constraints to the top of the cell to the top of that view, then the bottom of the view to the top of the first label, bottom of first label to the top of the second label, and bottom of second label to bottom of cell.
3. Load the .xib into the viewcontroller and register it with the collectionView on `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   let nib = UINib(nibName: CustomCellName, bundle: nil)
   self.collectionView!.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCellID")`
   ```
4. Load a second copy of that xib into the class and store it as a property so you can use it to determine the size of what that cell should be

   ```
   let sizingNibNew = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(CustomCellName, owner: CustomCellName.self, options: nil) as NSArray
   self.sizingNibNew = (sizingNibNew.objectAtIndex(0) as? CustomViewCell)!
   ```
5. Implement the `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` in your view controller.  The method that matters is called `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.  Inside that method you will need to pull the data from the datasource that is associated with that cell from the indexPath.  Then configure the sizingCell and call `preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize`.  The method returns a CGSize which will consist of the width minus the content insets and the height that is returned from `self.sizingCell.preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize(targetSize)`.

   ```
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
       guard let data = datasourceArray?[indexPath.item] else {
           return CGSizeZero
       }
       let sectionInset = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset
       let widthToSubtract = sectionInset!.left + sectionInset!.right

       let requiredWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width


       let targetSize = CGSize(width: requiredWidth, height: 0)

       sizingNibNew.configureCell(data as! CustomCellData, delegate: self)
       let adequateSize = self.sizingNibNew.preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize(targetSize)
       return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView?.bounds.width)! - widthToSubtract, height: adequateSize.height)
    }
   ```
6. In the class of the custom cell itself you will need to override `awakeFromNib` and tell the `contentView` that its size needs to be flexible

   ```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
    }
   ```
7. In the custom cell override `layoutSubviews`

   ```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
      self.layoutIfNeeded()
     }
   ```
8. In the class of the custom cell implement `preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize`.  This is where you will need to do any trickery on the items that are being laid out.  If its a label you will need to tell it what its preferredMaxWidth should be.

   ```
   func preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize(_ targetSize: CGSize)-> CGSize {

       let originalFrame = self.frame
       let originalPreferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth


       var frame = self.frame
       frame.size = targetSize
       self.frame = frame

       self.setNeedsLayout()
       self.layoutIfNeeded()
       self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.questionLabel.bounds.size.width


       // calling this tells the cell to figure out a size for it based on the current items set
       let computedSize = self.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

       let newSize = CGSize(width:targetSize.width, height:computedSize.height)

       self.frame = originalFrame
       self.questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = originalPreferredMaxLayoutWidth

       return newSize
   }
   ```

All those steps should give you the correct sizes.  If your getting 0 or other funky numbers than you haven't set up your constraints properly.

Comment: This is a great bit of code bolnad. Really helped me out. I had a cell with a stackpanel and two expanding labels inside - the cell now expands to fit the contents!

Comment: @JamesMundy thanks for the comment, I was hoping it would help clear it up for someone!

Comment: @bolnad : Bingo! It Worked. But I want to create a auto-expanding cell based on which expands/contracts on selection .. Any ideas?

Comment: @AbhishekBedi not sure what your asking, sounds like you want to create an insert cell when tapping on another cell? Kind of how apple does their inline picker in the calendar app?

Comment: Actually I have a tableview with dynamic number of cells inside a collection view cell.  When the user taps on the cell then the table should expand / contract and accordingly the size of the cell be increased /decreased

Comment: This solution worked a treat for me. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I found that I didn't need step 6 (autoresizing mask) or step 7 (layoutSubviews). Step 8 I only used `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` and skipped setting the labels preferred max layout width. (However, I did have to adjust the width of my sizing cell frame to the width of the collection view.)

Comment: thank you sir you saved me a lottttt of hours

Comment: Why is iOS so... painful? In android's ListView (or other recyclers) we just return views, that's all. Size must be determined by view, not by collection's view controller.

Comment: I think you can replace the following lines `var frame = self.frame; frame.size = targetSize; self.frame = frame;` with just `self.frame.size = targetSize`

Comment: I find this to be quite the performance hit when working with larger number of elements since it requires every single one to be calculated at start due to the `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` is being called for each cell when initalization happens. Is there a way to limit this to only the visible view port of elements or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SemyonDanilov SwiftUI has made grids easier but performance sensitive code is still living hell!

Answer (score 27):

We can maintain dynamic height for collection view cell without xib(only using storyboard).

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSAttributedString* labelString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your long string goes here" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]}];
        CGRect cellRect = [labelString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellRect.size.height);
}
```

Make sure that numberOfLines in IB should be 0.

Comment: wish I could vote this up twice!

Comment: Such a simple solution! I made a static function in my collection view cell to perform this calculation and return the height.

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 4.***

I have created a Xib for UICollectionViewCell which seems to be the good approach.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return size(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    private func size(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // load cell from Xib
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ACollectionViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ACollectionViewCell

        // configure cell with data in it
        let data = self.data[indexPath.item]
        cell.configure(withData: data)

        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        // width that you want
        let width = collectionView.frame.width
        let height: CGFloat = 0

        let targetSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        // get size with width that you want and automatic height
        let size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
        // if you want height and width both to be dynamic use below
        // let size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

        return size
    }
}
```

#note: I don't recommend setting image when configuring data in this size determining case. It gave me the distorted/unwanted result. Configuring texts only gave me below result.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR: Scan down to image, and then check out [working project here.](https://github.com/chrislconover/CollectionView-AutoLayout)

Updating my answer for a simpler solution that I found..

In my case, I wanted to fix the width, and have variable height cells.  I wanted a drop in, reusable solution that handled rotation and didn't require a lot of intervention.

What I arrived at, was override (just) `systemLayoutFitting(...)` in the collection cell (in this case a base class for me), and first defeat UICollectionView's effort to set the wrong dimension on `contentView` by adding a constraint for the known dimension, in this case, the width.

```
class EstimatedWidthCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        _ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority
        horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority,
        verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

        width.constant = targetSize.width
```

and then return the final size for the cell - used for (and this feels like a bug) the dimension of the cell itself, but not `contentView` - which is otherwise constrained to a conflicting size (hence the constraint above). To calculate the correct cell size, I use a lower priority for the dimension that I wanted to float, and I get back the height required to fit the content within the width to which I want to fix:

```
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
            CGSize(width: targetSize.width, height: 1),
            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
            verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)

        print("\(#function) \(#line) \(targetSize) -> \(size)")
        return size
    }

    lazy var width: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return contentView.widthAnchor
            .constraint(equalToConstant: bounds.size.width)
            .isActive(true)
    }()
}
```

But where does this width come from? It is configured via the `estimatedItemSize` on the collection view's flow layout:

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let view = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    view.backgroundColor = .cyan
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

lazy var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let width = view.bounds.size.width // should adjust for inset
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 10)
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    return layout
}()
```

Finally, to handle rotation, I implement `trailCollectionDidChange` to invalidate the layout:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: 10)
    layout.invalidateLayout()
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
}
```

The final result looks like this:

[image]

And I have published [a working sample here.](https://github.com/chrislconover/CollectionView-AutoLayout)

Comment: thanks, i could kiss you right now

Comment: It seems to be the best answers as it doesn't need to use external Nib (.xib) for Collection View Cell. So this solution is most flexible. More over It is abstracted to UICollectionViewCell superclass that can be just inherited and reused. So you can make such AutomaticWidthCell, AutomaticHeightCell, AutomaticSizeCell, and only set estimatedItemSize on CollectionView Layout. I have used this with StackViews in UICollectionViewCell, so hidding some elements easily collapses Cell layout

Comment: Nice solution but I just wanted to say that you shouldn't be handling rotation in `trailCollectionDidChange`, it gets called for the change of any trait and you may be invalidating the layout when it's not needed.  `viewWillTransition` is the right place.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like it's quite a popular question, so I will try to make my humble contribution.

---

The code below is **Swift 4** solution for no-storyboard setup. It utilizes some approaches from previous answers, therefore it prevents Auto Layout warning caused on device rotation.

I am sorry if code samples are a bit long. I want to provide an "easy-to-use" solution fully hosted by StackOverflow. If you have any suggestions to the post -  please, share the idea and I will update it accordingly.

#### The setup:

Two classes: `ViewController.swift` and `MultilineLabelCell.swift` - Cell containing single `UILabel`.

#### `MultilineLabelCell.swift`

```
import UIKit

class MultilineLabelCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseId = "MultilineLabelCellReuseId"

    private let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        let labelInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: labelInset.top).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: labelInset.left).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: labelInset.right).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: labelInset.bottom).isActive = true

        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Storyboards are quicker, easier, more seductive. Not stronger then Code.")
    }

    func configure(text: String?) {
        label.text = text
    }

    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = layoutAttributes.size.width - contentView.layoutMargins.left - contentView.layoutMargins.left
        layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

#### `ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

let samuelQuotes = [
    "Samuel says", 
    "Add different length strings here for better testing"
]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private(set) var collectionView: UICollectionView

    // Initializers
    init() {
        // Create new `UICollectionView` and set `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as its layout
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // Create new `UICollectionView` and set `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as its layout
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Dynamic size sample"

        // Register Cells
        collectionView.register(MultilineLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MultilineLabelCell.reuseId)

        // Add `coolectionView` to display hierarchy and setup its appearance
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

        // Setup Autolayout constraints
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        // Setup `dataSource` and `delegate`
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInsetReference = .fromLayoutMargins
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource -
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MultilineLabelCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! MultilineLabelCell
        cell.configure(text: samuelQuotes[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return samuelQuotes.count
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout -
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let sectionInset = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset
        let referenceHeight: CGFloat = 100 // Approximate height of your cell
        let referenceWidth = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width
            - sectionInset.left
            - sectionInset.right
            - collectionView.contentInset.left
            - collectionView.contentInset.right
        return CGSize(width: referenceWidth, height: referenceHeight)
    }
}
```

To run this sample create new Xcode project, create corresponding files and replace `AppDelegate` contents with the following code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        if let window = window {
            let vc = ViewController()
            navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            window.rootViewController = navigationController
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 answer based on helpful answer from @mbm29414.

Unfortunately, it requires the use of a XIB file. There doesn't appear to be an alternative.

The key parts are using a sizing cell (created only once) and registering the XIB when initializing the collection view.

Then you size each cell dynamically within the `sizeForItemAt` function.

```
// UICollectionView Vars and Constants
let CellXIBName = YouViewCell.XIBName
let CellReuseID = YouViewCell.ReuseID
var sizingCell = YouViewCell()


fileprivate func initCollectionView() {
    // Connect to view controller
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    // Register XIB
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: CellXIBName, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellReuseID)

    // Create sizing cell for dynamically sizing cells
    sizingCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(CellXIBName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! YourViewCell

    // Set scroll direction
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

    // Set properties
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false

    // Set top/bottom padding
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: collectionViewTopPadding, left: collectionViewSidePadding, bottom: collectionViewBottomPadding, right: collectionViewSidePadding)

    // Hide scrollers
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Get cell data and render post
    let data = YourData[indexPath.row]
    sizingCell.renderCell(data: data)

    // Get cell size
    sizingCell.setNeedsLayout()
    sizingCell.layoutIfNeeded()
    let cellSize = sizingCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)

    // Return cell size
    return cellSize
}
```

Comment: Let's see if I got this right. `YouViewCell ` is not your actual cell class or actual cell Xib? It is specifically created to deal with sizing? Or... do I have to pull my actual cell *designs* out of my Storyboard and put them in separate Xibs?

Comment: This worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps mentioned in this SO and everything is fine except when my Collection View has less data (text) to make it wide enough.  Checking the documentation in `systemLyaoutSizeFittingSize`, I have this solution so my cell take up the width as I requested:

```
- (CGSize)calculateSizeForSizingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)sizingCell width:(CGFloat)width {
    CGRect frame = sizingCell.frame;
    frame.size.width = width;
    sizingCell.frame = frame;
    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize
                        withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                              verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel];
    return size;
}
```

Hope this would help someone.

```
- (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Apple doc:

> Equivalent to sending -systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority: with UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel for both priorities.

While the default value is "pretty low" according to Apple's doc:

> When you send -[UIView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:], the size fitting most closely to the target size (the argument) is computed.  UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel is the priority level with which the view wants to conform to the target size in that computation.  It's quite low.  It is generally not appropriate to make a constraint at exactly this priority.  You want to be higher or lower.

So my change of default behavior is to enforce the width (horizontal fitting) with `UILayoutPriorityRequired`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow bolnad [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34109787/1049134) up to Step 4.

Then make it simpler by replacing all the other steps with:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // Configure your cell
    sizingNibNew.configureCell(data as! CustomCellData, delegate: self)

    // We use the full width minus insets
    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width - collectionView.sectionInset.left - collectionView.sectionInset.right

    // Constrain our cell to this width 
    let height = sizingNibNew.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: width, height: .infinity), withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel).height

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, hope you too.

*Note: I have used auto layout in Nib, remember add top and bottom contraints for subviews in contentView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           let cell = YourCollectionViewCell.instantiateFromNib()
           cell.frame.size.width = collectionView.frame.width
           cell.data = viewModel.data[indexPath.item]
           let resizing = cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.required, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel)
           return resizing
    }
```