# How can change UICollectionView cell height dynamically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating on `UICollectionView` for showing some data which are coming from server. But I have to set that cell height dynamically according to text size. I am creating a custom cell for `UICollectionView`.

Retrieve that `UICollectionView` cell in my `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Custom_CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.noteBookmarkCollectinView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Below Delegate method for `UICollectionView`:

```
 #pragma mark Collection view layout things

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
 }
 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return noteDetailsArr.count;
 }    
 - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4.0;
 }
 - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4.0;
 }
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,4,0,4);  // top, left, bottom, right
 }
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    return CGSizeMake(154, 154); // This is my fixed Cell height

   //Before I am trying this below code also, but its not working
    return [(NSString*)[contentArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithAttributes:NULL];
 }
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    Custom_CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.contentLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
   cell.contentLbl.tag = indexPath.row;

   cell.contentLbl.text = [contentArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [cell.contentLbl sizeToFit];

   return cell;
}
```

My result is coming like this :

[image]

**Notes: Green color is Cell background color & Pink color is label BG Color.**

And when I scroll the `CollectionView` I am able to see like below Image & After scroll again its coming perfect (Only for last row)

[image]

How can I make the cell height dynamically according to text. please Help me. I am stuck from last 1 week.

Comment: Here is a good example about how to deal with it.Click [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161839/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height#answer-28161915

Comment: I already tried this one, but its not working man

Comment: @Catalina T: I need the cell height will be same as label height according to text

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

```
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString * string = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]


    //CALCULATE text SIZE:
    CGSize textSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:NULL];
    return textSize;
}
```