# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with self sizing cells crash after reloadData

Tags: crash, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with non-zero `estimatedItemSize` for cells. I add and remove cells inside the collectionView reloading the data and sometimes I get a crash when I try to scroll to a cell that has just been removed/added.

Using backtrace tool, I get the following result:

> frame #9: 0x0000000185c8385c CoreFoundation-[__NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndex:] + 264     frame #10: 0x000000018aeabb18
>   UIKit-[_UIFlowLayoutSection setSize:forItemAtIndexPath:] + 708
>       frame #11: 0x000000018ae7cc5c UIKit-[UICollectionViewFlowLayout invalidationContextForPreferredLayoutAttributes:withOriginalAttributes:]
>   + 156
>       frame #12: 0x000000018ae646c4 UIKit-[UICollectionView _checkForPreferredAttributesInView:originalAttributes:] + 212
>       frame #13: 0x000000018a844968 UIKit-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
>   + 776

I have a guess that my flow layout could cache the cells.

**UPDATE:**
My issue appears on iOS 8.3, but not on previous versions, 8.2 included.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use self-sizing cell with non-zero `estimatedItemSize`. It's a trap.

Implement a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`'s method `collectionView(collectionView:collectionViewLayout:indexPath:)` where you calculate the size of the cell by calling `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` on a custom instance of the cell.

You can find more detailed info in this question: [UICollectionView - dynamic cell height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161839/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height)

Comment: A proper answer could be "don't use self-sizing cells :) "