# hiding tableview cells when the data fetched is nil thus reducing cell size

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview inside a collection view cell.  The tableview displays data which has been fetched.  Although, the data fetched is sometimes nil and ends up looking like this:[image]

In this case the company has no facebook name.  At the moment I'm hard coding the tableview cell count:

```
var arrayForContactList : NSMutableArray = []
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
    setupContactList()
}

func setupContactList() {

    if let phoneNumber = selectedCompany.phoneNumber {

        let dictionaryForContact = NSDictionary()
        dictionaryForContact.setValue("Phone", forKey: "Title")
        dictionaryForContact.setValue(phoneNumber, forKey: "Detail")
        arrayForContactList.addObject(dictionaryForContact)
    }
    // And the rest...

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
}
```

as for displaying the data in the tableview:

```
let contactArray = ["Phone", "Website", "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook", "Instagram"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID") as! ContactCell

    cell.contactLabel.text = arrayForContactList[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Title") as? String
    cell.contactButton.setTitle(arrayForContactList[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Detail") as? String, forState: .Normal)

    return cell
}
```

What I want to do reduce the size of the tableview by deleting cell(s) if the data = nil. Then, on top of that I want to decrease the size of the collectionview cell that the tableview sits in if cells from the tableview have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using tableview inside Collectionview i don't know whether it will work for you.Any how give it a try.

- Let's start with **numberOfSectionsInTableView** in tableview

  ```
  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 6
  }
  ```
- Modify your **numberOfRowsInSection** method with following code.

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return selectedCompany.phoneNumber! ? 1 : 0
    }else if section == 1 {
        return selectedCompany.website! ? 1 : 0
    }else if section == 2 {
        return selectedCompany.email! ? 1 : 0
    }else if section == 3 {
        return selectedCompany.twitter! ? 1 : 0
    }else if section == 4 {
        return selectedCompany.facebook! ? 1 : 0
    }else if section == 5 {
        return selectedCompany.instagram! ? 1 : 0
  }
  }
  ```
- **FYI** -Let me explain what we are doing, We gonna make every contact detail as seprate section and every section will have **1 or 0** depending on the availablity of the data
- Let's jump into **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID") as! ContactCell
     if indexPath.section == 0 {
         cell.contactLabel.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.contactButton.setTitle(selectedCompany.phoneNumber!, forState: .Normal)
     }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
         cell.contactLabel.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.contactButton.setTitle(selectedCompany.website!, forState: .Normal)
     }else if indexPath.section == 2 {
         cell.contactLabel.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.contactButton.setTitle(selectedCompany.email!, forState: .Normal)
     }else if indexPath.section == 3 {
         cell.contactLabel.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.contactButton.setTitle(selectedCompany.twitter!, forState: .Normal)
     }else if indexPath.section == 4 {
         cell.contactLabel.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.contactButton.setTitle(selectedCompany.facebook!, forState: .Normal)
     }else if indexPath.section == 5 {
         cell.contactLabel.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.contactButton.setTitle(selectedCompany.instagram!, forState: .Normal)
     }
     return cell
  }
  ```
- That's it now depending on availability of rows in section we gonna add contact details.
- For instance if we don't have **Facebook details** then **Section 4** will have **0 number of rows** if it so while loading section 4 **cellForRowAtIndexPath** will not be called.

**EDIT:** Try using `return selectedCompany.website!.isEmpty ? 1 : 0` **OR** some if condition to find the string is empty or not.like this

```
let str:String!
if str.characters.count != 0 {
    return 1
}else{
    return 0
}
```

in our case

```
if selectedCompany.phoneNumber!.characters.count != 0 {
    return 1
}else{
    return 0
}
```

Comment: under numberOfRows in section I get 'String' does not conform to protocol BooleanType

Comment: seems to be returning 1 section everytime. EDIT: Tell a lie it works. Forgot to add number of sections. You are a saviour!

Comment: Welcome luke,if you need any help let me know.have a great day.happy coding.

Comment: I don't have that much experience on collection view dynamic height..[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161839/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height) may help.If i found something useful i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
return 6
```

you need to return amount of cells, if you don't want that many count how many do you need

Comment: I know, but even when i return linkArray.count there is no difference in the amount of cells returned. When data is nil the cells are still displayed without any data

Comment: so you are returning .count of wrong thing, make different array with values that you have

Comment: Which is where I'm having problems. How do I create an array that only has none nil values?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding following method in your code:

```
    // when you get all the values call below code

    var arrayForContactList : NSMutableArray

    if let phoneNumber = selectedCompany.phoneNumber! {

        let dictionaryForContact : NSDictionary
        dictionaryForContact.setValue("Phone", forKey: "Title")
        dictionaryForContact.setValue(phoneNumber, forKey: "Detail")
        arrayForContactList.addObject(dictionaryForContact)
    }
    // Likewise do this for all your fields

    self.tableView.reload()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayForContactList.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID") as! ContactCell

    cell.contactLabel.text = arrayForContactList[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Title") as? String
    cell.contactButton.setTitle(arrayForContactList[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Detail") as? String, forState: .Normal)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I have modified my answer, give try !

Comment: I'm getting all sorts of errors.  Remember this is inside a collection view cell rather than a view controller which makes it a little more tricky, and complicated.

Comment: so you have do this modification in the collection view array also, Since your table view is the subpart of the collection view.

Comment: I edited my code. Not sure what you mean by modification in the collection view array. The arrayForContactList always seems to return nil now.

Comment: I meant to say that how you displaying the collection view? In the modified code you did not get anything inside the arrayForContactList? make sure you called this after getting response from server.

Comment: yeah It's empty. I tried to call setupContactList in viewdidload of the vc and pass the data through the cells and now get the nsexception error this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Title.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118618/discussion-between-suhas-patil-and-luke).