# Multiple cell types in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I had created two type of cells for my CollectionView, both are of different heights.

[image]

But when I run the app, the black cell is cut in half. I am unable to understand why. I tried changing the size of the cell, but it in turn makes the black cell over lap the cell below it. Please help with this.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Its because the height of the cell in collectionview is same for both the custom cells.

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal No, both cells are having different heights. The black one is 218 and the other one is 108

Answer (score 0):

The size of the CollectionView item has to be changed dynamically. Kindly follow the following link to solve

[UICollectionView - dynamic cell height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161839/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height)