# How to create collectionview with dynamic height as per the content in it?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

Souce Code : [My code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tiumEJu3YyihlQByjuedowVsJb_wRhe5/view?usp=sharing)

I need to create layout having dynamic size as per the text of different length, for that using collectionview inside tableview cell

I have created custom collectionview with self sizing collectionview cell in it. I have used CustomFlowLayout(sub class of UICollectionViewLayout) with prepare override method to calculate size of each cell.

I am able to achieve the dynamic size collectionview cell, now I need to make collectionview height dynamic based on its content size, as of now I have taken height contstraint of collectionview and set it as 200 fixed.

Need help regarding how to set collectionview height dynamically based on its content and at the same time adjust the parent tableview cell to fit the its content

Below is the screenshot of what I want to achieve, Thanks much!

[image: DynamicContentSize]

Comment: If you are showing list, then why to use collection, use table. Or do you have any specific design challenge? Let us know.

Comment: Requirement is as such that we need to show list with dynamic size, if two small words are there then it should be placed side by side not up and down

Comment: You need to use table view instead of collection view.

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomFlowLayout which is subclass of UICollectionViewLayout you need to override the collectionViewContentSize as shown below.

Calculate your content height & return it.

```
override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: contentHeight)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your collection view height using

```
if heightConstraint.constant != collectionView.contentSize.height {
    heightConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
    view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}
```

And you can set your tableview row height as automatic. if your contraints are proper the tableview cell will automatically adjust its height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to adjust the size of collectionview, but tableview cell is not adjusting based on updated collectionview size, though tableview size is dynamic

Comment: Are your collection view constraints properly set inside a tableview cell?

Comment: Yes, constraints are set properly

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102033/7388630

You can get fully working and explained code sample [here](https://fewlinesofcode.com/swift,/uicollectionview/2018/11/01/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height.html)

Comment: Link for your fully working code sample is not working, can you please share the working one? Thanks

Comment: That’s actually weird. It works for me. https://fewlinesofcode.com/swift,/uicollectionview/2018/11/01/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height.html

Comment: Thanks for the new link, I was able to download your code, it seems your collection view is not resizing based on its cell size, your cell is resizing based on their content in your code label.