# UICollectionView, fix column with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, collectionview

I searched a lot about collectionView, but I did find a simple one, as the below,

1. My collectionView has 2 columns when Compact, 3 columns when
       Regular,
2. There are many cells, all the cells' height are the
       same, but not a fix number, which depends on some contents, but each
       cell's height are equal.

Comment: you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161839/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height) for create dynamic height of Cell

Comment: you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161915/11884701) for create dynamic height of Cell